# Should I consider atomic design as a kind of user-interface domain of my Domain driven desgin?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, domain-driven-design

I’m New to DDD

I did read two blog posts explaining how ddd diff with the MVVM pattern and suggest a different folder organisation with modules sharing an { app, router, store, eventBus } object.

My question is: Do atomic-designed-components can be seen as a kind of user-interface domain, sharring agnostics components.

So the other domains of the buisiness could call those generics elements ?? Is this a DDD pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

DDD is really not about patterns, but more about principles.

When considering if `x` is a domain, one should ask themselves if the of `x` is clearly defined, if `x` is self-sufficient, if `x` is well-separated from other things that interact with it.

I'm not familiar with the "atomic-designed-components" concept, however, in my opinion, a well-designed UI library can resemble a DDD-style Bounded Context. It's up to the user to figure out how the UI BC will interact with all the other BCs in the system.

A more narrow approach is to limit the application of Bounded-Context-thinking to the "server-side", i.e. to the components that perform business logic. This, however, is a needless restriction, if you ask me.

With regards to MVVM, MVP, MVC or any other architecture pattern, none of them contradict the DDD approach, yet none of them guarantee it out of the box.

Here is a [paper (PDF)](https://www.domainlanguage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/GettingStartedWithDDDWhenSurroundedByLegacySystemsV1.pdf) for the ways Bounded Contexts can interact. I hope you find it useful.